# Recurrence for A004208

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

Let $a(n)$ be [A004208](https://oeis.org/A004208). Here
$$a(n)=n\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(2j-1)-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}a(i)\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n-i}(2j-1)$$
I conjecture that
$$a(n)=R(n-1,0)$$
where
$$R(n,q)=2(q+2)R(n-1,q+1)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}R(n-1,j), R(0,q)=1$$
Is there a way to prove it?

I would also like to know if this type of recurrence is known in the literature, where instead of $2(q+2)$ we use an arbitrary function $g(q)$, and also modify the second part to
$$m\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}k^{q-j}R(n-1,j)$$
Here $m,k\in\mathbb{R}$.